# Spark - Random Function throws exception

Tags: apache-spark, hiveql, random-seed

Hi All I am trying to generate a random number for a couple of fields. One is a Alphanumeric one and another is a date datatype.

First I converted both the fields into an integer type and added them together. On top of this I am trying to apply the rand() function. It is working perfectly well in Hive but when I try to execute the same in Spark it is throwing the below mentioned error

```
SELECT
RAND(CAST(EMP_DEPT AS Int) + CAST(coalesce(PAY_DATE, CAST('1900-01-01' AS timestamp)) AS Int) * 1000000000) AS RANDOM_NUM
FROM EMPLOYEE
```

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Input argument to rand must be
>   an integer, long or null literal.;

Checked couple of posts here but did not find this scenario

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine the column type being fed into `RAND`. You can do this by removing `RAND` and looking at the schema. For example,

```
sql("select cast(coalesce(current_timestamp(), CAST('1900-01-01' AS timestamp)) AS Int) * 1000000000 as x").printSchema
```

produces

```
root
 |-- x: integer (nullable = false)
```

Comment: So your query produces an int but still RAND won't take it ?